# ¿En qué países la palabra "coger" tiene connotaciones sexuales?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, definiciones, coloquialismos, sexualidad

En algunos países hispanoparlantes la palabra *coger* tiene connotaciones sexuales. La RAE indica ["Realizar el acto sexual"](https://dle.rae.es/?w=coger), pero el problema es que es una expresión malsonante, marcada fuertemente como palabra tabú y conviene evitarla (salvo que quieras ser grosero).

Sé que esto es así al menos en Argentina y México, pero no estoy seguro de otros países. Siempre que intento buscar referencias estas indican que *coger* tiene este significado ["en casi todos los países americanos"](http://www.fondodeculturaeconomica.com/obras/suma/r3/buscar.asp?word2=agarrar,%20coger,%20tomar) pero por lo que me han dicho colombianos y venelozanos esto no es así en sus países. Creo que en Cuba y Costa Rica tampoco.

Entiendo que hay más de 20 países hispanohablantes, pero puede alguien confirmarme ¿**en qué países la palabra *coger* tiene connotaciones sexuales**? Me gustaría saber a qué atenerme cuando hable con personas de estos países.

Comment: Seguramente conoces ese chascarrillo sobre un español que pregunta en Argentina dónde puede coger el autobús, y le contestan: como no sea por el tubo de escape...

Comment: @Gorpik, Ja, que bueno! Yo aprendi sobre esta diferencia por un amigo espaniol, de padres argentinos, que cuando fue a visitar a sus abuelos alli a La Pampa, queriendo sostener a la mascota de la familia, dijo un dia "Voy a coger al gato". La abuela, claro, escandalizada.

Comment: Aclaro que incluso en Argentina (donde la palabra se usa sólo en la acepción sexual) la gente entiende que en España (al menos) quiere decir otra "agarrar", y no sorprende ni escandaliza escuchar la palabra en boca de españoles (o, en general, extranjeros). Lo mismo con "concha" y otras.

Comment: Los Catalanes suelen decir _la Elena_ _el Juan_ etc. También, Concha, es un nombre normal y corriente. Imaginen la sorpresa de un amigo Argentino, recién llegado a Barcelona cuando unos colegas le dicen "Pasamos a cojer a la Concha y después vamos a cenar".

Comment: Relacionada: En [Coger: origen de su significado sexual en algunos países](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33217/5481) se explica por qué y cuándo "coger" tiene connotaciones sexuales.

Answer (score 23):

De acuerdo a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanophone), salen 25 países de habla hispana. Con lo que cada uno aporte, podemos actualizar esta lista, porque no sé si va a ser posible que una sola persona aporte una lista completa.

### País/territorio

## Sí

- Argentina
- Costa Rica
- El Salvador
- Guatemala
- Honduras
- México
- Nicaragua
- Paraguay
- Uruguay
- Venezuela

## No

- Colombia
- Chile
- Cuba
- Ecuador
- España
- Panamá
- Perú
- Puerto Rico
- República Dominicana
- Sáhara Occidental

## Depende

- Estados Unidos (influencias mexicanas, cubanas, dominicanas y puertorriqueñas. Ver comentarios de Guifa)

## Sin datos aún

- Filipinas
- Guinea Ecuatorial

Gracias a todos.

He usado [esta referencia](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=945172) para Uruguay, Chile y Bolivia. El problema es que también cita Venezuela como `sí`, cuando ya la teníamos como `no`, así que no estoy seguro de cuánto fiarme de ella...

Comment: Conocí un saharahui y usaba coger como España, y aún sin ese indicio, por la cercanía territorial y relación cultural, creo que puedes ponerles ya el "No".

Comment: En EEUU sería *depende*. El español occidental sigue más el mejicano, el oriental más el cubano y el neoyorquino una mezcla del dominicano y cubano.

Comment: Y puertorriqueño en NY claro jaja

Comment: Tengo que ponerme a inverstigar todos esos que estan en blanco todavia...

Comment: Habria q ver uruguay, a mi se me parecen mucho en la forma de hablar a los argentinos aunque se odien entre ellos...lol

Comment: He actualizado algunos con [esta información](http://www.asihablamos.com/significado/palabra/coger) pero esta fuente contradice lo que ya teníamos para Venezuela y Colombia... :-(

Comment: Soy Venezolano y la palabra "coger" tiene toda la connotación sexual, también utilizamos (tirar, puyar, culiar).

Comment: Hay una respuesta nueva que asegura que en Venezuela sí se usa con sentido sexual. Puesto que tenemos varias fuentes coincidentes, actualizo la información sobre ese país.

Comment: Añadí hoy nuevos con [esta referencia](http://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/index.php?pais=&palabra=coger&submit=Buscar&tipobusqueda=0), que desgraciadamente contradice Panamá. Incluye: Salvador, Guatemala y Honduras, que no los teníamos.

Comment: En Colombia definitivamente no.  De hecho es la palabra mas usada y casi no se usa ninguno de sus sinónimos.

Comment: Bueno, aca en Puerto rico se usa la palabra cojer que es como agarrar, y no veo que yo fuera a usa y encuentre a un mexicano-na y diga esta palabra pues le explicare lo que quiero decir y si me corrige yo le dire soy boricua y de habla hispana. ay que ser claros, porque muchos de ellos cren que lo digo en el sentido de sexo.

Comment: Coger no es mala palabra en Ecuador.

Comment: Bolivia: sí. Es correcto.

Comment: @Diego ¿Esto debería ser Community Wiki ?

Comment: http://dle.rae.es/?id=9fC4QbW _recoge_ que ese sentido **_si_** se aplica en la República Dominicana

Comment: Suscribo lo que dice @Rodrigo en su respuesta: en Chile se entiende, y a veces incluso se usa, pero como quien sabe que usa un giro extranjero. Si en algún caso está asentado, es sólo en un ámbito reducido.

Comment: En México **coger** no tiene connotación sexual. Significa tomar. Quizá lo confunden con **cojer**, lo cual sí tiene el sentido sexual a que hacen alusión. Aunque entiendo que cojer no tiene aceptación ante la RAE.

Answer (score 7):

En Chile sabemos que el resto del mundo usa "coger" con significado sexual, y podríamos usarlo, pero la palabra no ha asentado. Se puede entender con picardía en situaciones coloquiales y se puede elaborar textos chistosos al respecto, pero nadie diría (ni educada ni groseramente) "vamos a coger".

Y me salgo del tema pero aprovecho de completar:
En Chile, en algunas épocas se ha dicho "tirar" ("en esa época tirábamos") y cierto uso modificado de "dar" ("estuvieron dándole", "le dieron"). El "dar" puede ser dativo ("le dieron [a ella] toda la mañana") o recípoco ("le dieron [ambos] toda la tarde").

Pero la palabra preferida por décadas en Chile ha sido "culiar".

Answer (score 4):

México, aquí "coger" ya perdió el significado de "sostener" y fue sustituido por completo por "agarrar" y "tomar" principalmente. Ahora "coger" sólo significa tener relaciones sexuales, pero se entiende por completo si hablamos con personas de otro país.

Comment: Hace algunos años una amiga de vacaciones en Mexico no sabía dónde estaba la parada de autobús y preguntaba por la calle "¿Dónde se coge el autobús?" y se reían mucho

Comment: Lo interesante es que como "recoger" no hay tanto problema aunque tambien suena con connotacion sexual pero no hay palabra para sustituirlo. Por ejemplo "recoge la basura", "ve y recoge a Laura en la parada de autobuses".

Comment: Quizá te refieras a **cojer** (f...) que es enteramente distinto de **coger** (take).

Comment: Cojer no existe en ningún dialecto. Es sencillamente una falta de ortografía.

Answer (score 4):

En Cuba no hay problema alguno. Así mi tiempo allí estuvo muy bien ya que uso la palabra cada dos por tres y no tenía por qué cambiar mi habla. Mi inquilino, que es argentino, me dijo que con ambos significados está corriente, pero igual es algo viejo él y lleva un tiempo fuera del país, así que la situación puede haber cambiado. Dudo que tenga connotaciones sexuales en el español africano.

Voy a confirmarlo con un colega peruano hoy pero creo que me dijo algo parecido, que usarlo con el significado no sexual no corre ningún riesgo de ser entendido como el sexual.  Bueno, no pude hablar con él, pero en [este hilo](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=67092), dicen que en el Perú no hay significado sexual.  En el mismo, dice que mantiene el significado no sexual en la R.D., el Panamá y la Colombia, y que según quien creas del hilo sigue o con ambos significados en Venezuela o solo el no sexual (confío más en que usarían ambos).

Edit: acabo de conocer a una panameña hoy mismo que es profesora de secundaria. Usó coger en la conversación igual que lo usaría yo (es decir, sin connotación sexual). Le pregunté si así es común y me dijo que allí no tiene el significado sexual.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Seria muy util si puedieras confirmar el español africano, porque ni se me habia pasado por la cabeza. Yo tambien supongo que tendra influencias del español "europeo" y no sera el caso.

Answer (score 4):

En Perú puedes usar la palabra, normalmente en frases como: “voy a coger la taza”, “voy a coger el tren”,  “Lo cogí del cabello”, etc.  La palabra “coger”, no tiene sentido sexual intrínseco, sólo  adquiere connotación sexual si la utilizas en determinados contextos, vinculando a 2 personas, es decir referenciando o mencionando directamente el nombre de una persona: “Me cogí a “x” toda la noche”. En Perú se utiliza la palabra “cachar”, en nuestro país esta palabra si tiene un sentido sexual intrínseco, pero la palabra “coger”, no.

Comment: ¿Entonces con la connotación sexual en el Perú *coger* es pronominal en vez de transitivo?

Comment: Definitivamente es pronominal.Pero una frase como: “Ernesto cogió a Rebeca”, puede generar dos interpretaciones. 1) Ernesto sostuvo a rebeca. 2) Ernesto tuvo sexo con Rebeca.( Aún así, la mayoria de personas interpretara la frase como, Ernesto sostuvo a Rebeca) Si la frase está en un contexto como: “Ernesto cogió a Rebeca para que no se caiga”, se interpretara como, Ernesto agarro o sostuvo a Rebeca, es decir no habra ninguna connotacion sexual

Answer (score 3):

Soy cubano y puedo confirmar que en Cuba no tiene significado sexual alguno. De hecho, van a escuchar en una conversación normal varias veces la palabra. Y es poco probable que se utilice con ese sentido a no ser entre dos personas que lo tengan establecido como código a la hora de hacer bromas.

Viví un tiempo en Venezuela y allí sí que le dan un significado sexual en ocasiones exagerado, a tal punto que he visto a mujeres ruborizarse cuando escuchan mucho la palabra de alguien no acostumbrado a que tenga ese significado (como me pasaba a mí al inicio). Pero también es pura malicia que de forma general se le dé esa connotación a la palabra. No creo que perdiera su significado completamente porque en algunas conversaciones podías escuchar la palabra con el significado de "agarrar" algo y no pasaba nada.

Comment: ¿Malicia?  ¿De veras?

Comment: @aparente001 he actualizado la respuesta con un punto que me acabo de dar cuenta de que faltaba en la oración. Lo de pura malicia me refiero a que las personas toman con maldad la frase cuando uno no la usa con ese sentido. No se si eso fue lo que no comprendiste.

Comment: Si una mujer se ruboriza no es por malicia, es porque de veras está incómoda.

Comment: @aparente001 por eso coloque el punto, voy a hacer otra edición para que se comprenda mejor.

Comment: Qué bueno tener confirmación "oficial" de alguien cubano. Tenemos distintas preguntas cuya respuesta depende del país, ¿podrás revisarlas para ver si lo que se comentó sobre Cuba es correcto? Están listadas [aquí](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2484/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui por supuesto que voy a ayudarles. Poco a poco ire mirando. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Queda inherente el sentido que se le quiere dar si decimos o escribimos:

> -Ernesto cogió a Rebeca [Él la agarró]
>
> -Ernesto se cogió a Rebeca [Él tuvo sexo con ella, no necesariamente correspondido]
>
> -Ernesto cogió lo de Rebeca [Él tomó y se llevó lo que era de ella]

Comment: Buena aclaración sobre el uso de la palabra Mario pero nota que la pregunta es sobre en qué países la palabra tiene un sentido sexual y no sobre cómo se usa o no ya que la persona que pregunta es de España y entiende perfectamente el uso.

Answer (score 1):

Según el Diccionario de americanismos, se usa [*coger*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=coger) así en los siguientes países:

> **I.   1.**    tr. prnl. *Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, RD, Ve, Ar, Ur,* vulg; pop; *Bo,* p.u, tabú.   Realizar el coito.