# ¿En qué países aplica la acepción anatómica de "pito"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos

En el DRAE:

> Pito
>
> 11. m. coloq. pene.

Esta acepción es conocida en Argentina, pero por lo que me dijeron, no es universal, ni siquiera en Sudamérica.

¿Alguien sabe a qué países aplica y a cuáles no?

Comment: En España la tiene. Mi recomendación es hacer como [en esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8749/5481) y crear tu propia respuesta con una lista de países, y que la gente vaya completando de forma colaborativa, pero no exclusiva. Creo que es muy difícil que una sola respuesta te pueda incluir todos los países de América latina, y vas a tener un montón de mini-respuestas o comentarios con "aquí sí" y "aquí no" y "aquí ademas le decimos tal o cual...".

Comment: @Diego veo que esto es lo que se  hizo. Eliminé alguna respuesta corta pues ya estaba reflejada en las ediciones ulteriores a la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: @tchrist ya que veo que editaste esta pregunta, te puede interesar leer la [lista de preguntas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2484/1674) cuya respuesta depende del país de habla hispana. Poco a poco vamos añadiendo elementos a la lista y completando los países en cada una de las respuestas. Mirando tu perfil veo que tienes un bagaje variopinto, por lo que puede que puedas aportar interesantes variantes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Países en los que **pito** significa pene:

- Argentina
- España
- México
- Colombia (en desuso)
- Paraguay
- Uruguay
- Cuba
- Guatemala

Países en los que no:

- Chile
- Ecuador
- El Salvador
- Costa Rica
- ¿Perú?
- Puerto Rico
- Venezuela

Comment: En México igual se dice pito.

Comment: He actualizado la lista de acuerdo a [esta referencia](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Pito.php). Los países en los que **no** son tentativos. Lo mismo alguien contradice esa referencia (por ejemplo, España no está en la lista de esa página, y el significado de _cigarrillo_ tb se da en otros países... Casi mejor confiar en lo que pueda aportar cada usuario).

Comment: En Colombia puede usarse, se uso, pero actualmente su uso no es muy popular.

Comment: En Perú tiene doble significado: 1) silbato, 2) pene. Depende del contexto en que se use, pero no es un término común en las conversaciones coloquiales.

Comment: Como comentario pito en México también significa silbato pero casi siempre se toma como referencia al pene.

Comment: En Chile el uso formal es silbato. Informalmente es un sonido agudo y un cigarro de marihuana.

Answer (score 0):

En El Salvador más bien se dice coloquialmente ***Pico*** al pene.

*Pito* aunque sí se entiende, casi no se usa y no es normal utilizarlo.

Acá de hecho hay una planta que tiene una flor comestible que se llama pito y se lo ponen a la sopa de frijoles y se come de diferentes formas.

Un día le dijimos a unos mejicanos si querían tomarse una sopa de frijoles con Pito y se austaron. Eran dos y el mejicano me dijo: *yo le entro a la sopa y el Pito se lo das a mi compañero*. Ja, ja, ja.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta, Omar, y bienvenido a [spanish.se]!