# Uso de "estuve" y "estaba"

Tags: traducción, gramática

Can somebody please tell me how these sentences change meaning when using preterite vs. imperfect?  And maybe give some example sentences that illustrate the difference??
It is very hard, this concept, for a native English speaker.

Yo estaba en escuela

yo estuve en escuela

ella estaba en colorado

ella estuvo en colorado

yo estaba corriendo

yo estuve corriendo

Comment: You better show some effort: what did you try? what problems did you encounter? Voting to close with the reason "asking for translations".

Comment: This question has been asked [here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12548/estuve-vs-estaba) already, and has answers. And [here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=fue+era) is a list of questions about "fue" and "era", which is the same sort of difference as between "estuve" and "estaba".

Comment: "Estaba" usually implies that the action didn't finish; normally is accompanied with the action which interrupted the previous one; "estuve" can be used as a standalone sentence: "Ayer estuve en el cine" (period. I'm just telling the fact that yesterday I was at the cinema). "Ayer estaba en el cine" (okay, what happened next?) "cuando me di cuenta de que había dejado la lavadora en marcha".

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty simple thing to remember this:

`Estaba` is used somewhat like the Past Progressive in English.

`"Estaba en la calle cuando me llamaron."`

Means that at this time, when I have been called, I was on the Street / outside. The call interrupted that action, but it later continued. An action could be finished, but that´s not necessarily the case.

`Estuve` however indicates something that has indeed terminated. Pretty much like the past tense in English.

Comment: Do you see?. This is why I said that the difference is very subtle. What about if I say "Ayer estuve pintando la casa pero no alcancé a pintarla toda."  The action was not finished and may continue some other time, and "Ayer estaba pintando la casa cuando me llamaron" also means the action was interrupted, so it is not absolutely about finished and unfinished tasks. We need a better answer than this and than mine. "Estar" is one of the most complicated verbs in every language so I guess the answer should be as well long and complex.

Comment: well another thing is that many people - even natives don't use the correct form. :) And ideed estar is very difficult.

Comment: Well I'm sure I'm one of the natives that uses it correctly :-) . To make sure I made a short research and found this link [ESTAR](http://diccionario.reverso.net/espanol-ingles/estar) with a hundred sentences in Spanish using the verb **Estar** and their translation to English. I think it will help you a lot

Comment: That's a great link! Thanks. We should work on a bettr answer though to publish here... :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree partly with DGaleano, who said that "Estar es uno de los verbos mas complicados en todos los idiomas."
In English, "estar" (to be) it is pretty  straightforward, but English speakers (my American students are a good example) have problems distinguishing "ser" and "estar."
Here are the differences, explained with two acronyms:
SER (TO BE)

**General rule**
Ser is used to classify and identify permanent or lasting attributes. This acronym will help you remember the rule:  **DOCTOR** (**D**escription, **O**ccupation, **C**haracteristic, **T**ime, **O**rigin, and **R**elationship).

1) Description. Describe him or her

> YO SOY ALTA
>
> YO SOY HOMBRE

2) Occupation or profession

> YO SOY ESTUDIANTE
>
> ELLA ES ARTISTA.

The indefinite articles un, una, unos and unas are omitted when describing an occupation after the verb ser

3) Characteristic. Define the essential qualities of a person.

> ELLA ES INTELIGENTE

4) Origin. Describes the place a person is from or the material something is made from

> SOY DE NUEVA JERSEY
>
> LA MESA ES DE MADERA

5) Time. Includes days, dates, and hours. For hours, use es for 1 o´clock and son for all other hours

> ES LA 1 PM Y HOY ES MIÉRCOLES

6) Relationship.

> LUISA ES MI MADRE, MARCOS ES MI AMIGO

Even after someone dies or someone breaks up, relationships are described using ser. Religion are also described using ser since a religion is considered a relationship with a higher power. Relationships are a form of identity.

**ESTAR (TO BE)**
General rule

Estar is used mainly to indicate temporary situations or conditions and locations. This acronym will help you remember the rule:  **PLACE** (**P**osition, **L**ocation, **A**ction, **C**ondition, and **E**motion).

1)  Position. Describes the place or posture a person or thing is in.

> EL ESTÁ SENTADO

2) Location. Describes where someone or something is permanently, temporarily, actually, or conceptually

> YO ESTOY EN LA CIUDAD, LA CLASE ESTÁ ALLÁ

3) Action. Describes an ongoing action and uses the present progressive tense. In Spanish, death is an ongoing action, not a permanent state

> NOSOTROS ESTAMOS ESTUDIANDO, MI ABUELO ESTÁ MUERTO

4) Condition. The state of an object

> EL COMPUTADOR ESTÁ DAÑADO

5) Emotion or feeling. How a person is feeling at a certain moment, physically or emotionally

> YO ESTOY FELIZ, ELLAS ESTÁN CANSADAS, ÉL ESTÁ SENTADO

Comment: Aunque la pregunta tiene que ver con el pasado del verbo Estar, mi voto positivo por una muy ilustrativa explicación. Tal vez la puedas editar y agregar ejemplos usado el tiempo pasado.

Answer (score 0):

> Yo estaba en la escuela = I was in the school
>
> Yo estuve en la escuela = I was in the school
>
> ella estaba en colorado = She was in Colorado
>
> ella estuvo en colorado = She was in Colorado
>
> yo estaba corriendo = I was running
>
> yo estuve corriendo = I was running.

There is another set of sentences that could help you better express different times like these:

> Yo he estado en la escuela = I've been in the school
>
> Ella ha estado en Colorado = She has been in Colorado.
>
> Yo he estado corriendo = I've been running.

The difference between `Estaba` y `Estuve` is very subtle. Both are past but `Estaba` usually means that the action has finished and with `Estuve` the action could still be incomplete.

Comment: Es al revés: **estuve** es para una acción completada, y **estaba** para una acción incompleta.

Comment: **"Donde estabas ayer?. Yo estaba en mi casa"**. Eso no es una acción incompleta. Como lo dije en el otro comentario... **Estar** es uno de los verbos mas complicados en todos los idiomas y creo que necesitamos una respuesta más completa que la mía y que la de BenjB.

Comment: Que diga 'estaba en mi casa' no implica que sea completo, puede ser una interrupción de la acción 'estar en la casa,' algo así como 'estaba en mi casa pero salí a pasear.'

Comment: **"Donde estuviste ayer? Ayer estuve en mi casa."**  Es la misma pregunta y la misma respuesta e igualmente es una acción completa. Español es mi idioma nativo y estoy 100% seguro de que se usar _estaba_ y _estuve_ pero aparte de ejemplos como este no se explicar la diferencia claramente. Definitivamente la diferencia no esta en si la acción es completa o incompleta

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this debate (here and in linguistics) is that we are discussing phrases that nobody would say. They may seem grammatically correct, but they are unacceptable and unnatural without extra elements in the sentence or a clear context. This is not just a matter of "use" but a semantic issue. Some of the sentences above NEED more elements to be correct and there is a reason for that.

To the natives here: would you say "Ayer, yo estaba en la escuela" without anybody asking you where you were (because that person was wondering where you had been all this time) or without you explaining in relation to what you are talking about (Yo estaba en la escuela cuando...)? "Ayer yo estuve en la escuela", on the other hand, may be said just like that, in a diary, for instance.

The example sentences in the question follow a mathematical formula that does not belong in natural languages. They are stripping the sentences of all what makes them sentences from Spanish. @PonyVilla, this topic is related to **aspect**. In English it is there and you have it at a semantic level (although not grammatical level), so may be you can read more on the topic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect  It is a bit complex at the beginning, but once you understand this, it is going to change your life because aspect is everywhere in Spanish! :)

Comment: This is not an answer but....it is very interesting.