# ¿Cómo recoge el diccionario el uso de "entrar" en "Entrarle a una chica"?

Tags: verbos, dle, locuciones, acepciones

En España se usa la locución verbal

> Entrarle a una chica (o a un grupo de chicas)

para describir esa situación en la que quieres comenzar una conversación con una chica que te atrae y no conoces. Es decir, estando en un bar, discoteca, o incluso en otras situaciones (en clase, el supermercado, etc) alguien ve a una chica que le gusta pero no conoce y quiere "*entrarle*": ponerse hablar con ella, conocerla, y ver si se puede establecer una relación de algún tipo. Es decir, *entrarle* a una chica es el primer paso para *ligar* (es la connotación de esta locución).

El verbo [entrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FkLKqOW) tiene actualmente 32 acepciones en su entrada en el DRAE y ninguna parece recoger este uso, salvo quizá la 18a, o la 20a si se fuerza un poco el sentido.

> 18 intr. Llegar a ejercer influencia en el ánimo de alguien. *A Fulano no hay por donde entrarle*.
>
> 20 intr. Empezar a tener conocimiento o práctica de algo. *No pude entrarle a la lengua griega*.

Sin embargo veo que en las notas se incluyen dos locuciones verbales del tipo "entrarle a alguien o algo":

> entrarle a algo
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. El Salv., Méx. y Ur. Acometer una empresa.

(Para mí esta es casi la vigésima acepción que se exponía arriba, pero entiendo que se cita como locución de esos tres países en particular porque tiene un matiz distinto, un pelín más amplio que "Empezar a tener conocimiento")

> entrarle a alguien
>
> 1. loc. verb. Méx. Golpearlo.

Viendo eso, para mi la acepción que mejor se ajusta a "Entrarle a una chica (o a un grupo de chicas)" sería la decimoctava acepción: "*intentar* ejercer influencia sobre el ánimo de alguien", pero es discutible que el acto de "entrarle" a alguien y el llegar tener la oportunidad de hablar son dos cosas distintas (es decir, le entras a la chica, ella te dice "que te pires *pesao*" y le has entrado pero has tenido cero oportunidad de intentar influenciar su ánimo hacia ti). Aparte, el sentido es mucho más amplio en esa decimoctava acepción, ya que como explicaba antes, la connotación de "entrarle a una esa chica" es que quieres intentar ligártela.

Viendo que ninguna de las 32 acepciones realmente me cuadra, pero tampoco se recoge como una de las excepciones que se listan al final (esas locuciones verbales) me pregunto: ¿Cómo incluye el diccionario la acepción de "entrar" que se usa en "entrarle a una chica"?

¿Me equivoco yo y se recoge en alguna de esas 32 acepciones? ¿Falta y debería incluirse como una locución verbal aparte en las notas del final como un regionalismo? ¿Acaso se recoge este uso de otra manera en la que no me he dado cuenta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En mi opinión, si bien es bastante posible vincular este significado específico de *entrarle a alguien* con varias de las acepciones del DLE, debería haber una entrada aparte para la locución como se la usa en España, porque aunque el Diccionario no puede cubrir todos los posibles significados con sus usos figurativos, metafóricos y por extensión, está claro que esta locución tiene un uso muy particular.

Hay que observar que en México *entrarle a alguien* significa golpearlo; en Argentina, *entrarle a alguien* (en este contexto) se interpretaría más probablemente como lograr un contacto físico íntimo (sea cual fuere). De manera que sin una aclaración específica, un hablante que se encuentra con esto por primera vez tendría para elegir entre varias posibles interpretaciones sugeridas por el verbo *entrar*.

Quizá *entrarle a alguien* pueda interpretarse como una de las acepciones intransitivas de *entrar* (las que tienen que ver con pasar del exterior al interior de algo, o con dedicarse a algo) modificada por un [dativo de interés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there). Este uso sería paralelo a la locución *entrarle a algo*, que significa "acometer una empresa" y que figura en el DLE como propio de El Salvador, México y Uruguay; en Argentina se usa más habitualmente con el significado de "empezar a comer algo" (con la connotación de que lo que se come es mucho y/o que se come con muchas ganas).

Comment: Gracias. Esto me recuerda un poco a esas bromas sobre el verbo [coger](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8749/5481). Supongo que en México un "Voy a entrarle a esa chica" sería respondido con un "Pero por qué tio bruto!! Qué te ha hecho!!??". En otros países necesitaría aclaración. Primero pensé en redactar la pregunta para ver si se usaba igual fuera de España, pero sospechaba que no viendo esas locuciones, y la verdad es que coincido que lo suyo sería que tuviese su entrada aparte como locución.

Answer (score 1):

Consulté hace tiempo esta duda a la RAE a través de *Enclave RAE*. Se han tomado su tiempo en responder, pero básicamente me dicen que esa acepción se recoge en el *Diccionario del estudiante* en su acepción 14 (consulta solo posible a través de *Enclave*):

> 14. intr. coloq. Empezar alguien el trato o el contacto con otro. *Prueba a entrarle preguntándole por sus viajes. Para entrarme lo mejor es que me tuteen.*

Añaden que se trata de un uso coloquial propio del español europeo, y que también se recoge en el *Diccionario del español actual* (Seco, Andrés y Ramos; Aguilar, 2011 [2.ª ed.]), *s/v* entrar, 21 ('abordar [a alguien]').

Concluyen la respuesta dada de la siguiente forma:

> Le agradecemos su observación acerca de la ausencia de este uso en el *Diccionario de la lengua española*, que transmitimos al Instituto de Lexicografía.

Así que seguramente en el futuro veremos este uso de *entrar* reflejado adecuadamente en el DLE.