# What does "nano" mean in "Quiero cogerte...de lo nano"?

Tags: significado, coloquialismos, palabras-raras

I came across the sentence earlier:

> Quiero cogerte...de lo nano

I've looked for ages but can't find out what the word *nano* means.

How would you guys translate this sentence? I am very grateful for help!

Comment: Could we have the full sentence and where you saw it? Not necessarily a link but a context?

Comment: La palabra "nano" es una forma de referirse a alguien (como por ejemplo Hola guapo). Se suele usar en culturas urbanas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a typo. `Nano` [is a unit prefix meaning "one billionth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano-). It's the [same in Spanish](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QEElStJ), since these prefixes come from greek.

Probably the original sentence actually meant to say

> "Quiero cogerte... de **la mano**"

As an additional note, the catch or joke (in regards of that ellipsis) might be that the verb "coger" in some countries means literally "to fuck". See [¿En qué países la palabra “coger” tiene connotaciones sexuales?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8749/5481)

So "quiero cogerte..." might be ambiguous (I want to grab your.../ I want to fuck you) or directly misdirect to the meaning with sexual connotations, depending on the country, and the last part makes the joke by clarifying it was not sexual (it was actually I want to **grab** your hand).

Comment: Is "lo"  another typo? "Lo nano" makes no sense

Comment: Okay, thank you, that might be it! But what you said about it having different meanings in different countries, this is in Chile but the person who wrote it is from Colombia and I don't know what it means there...

Comment: @RuibioRic Pues no me había dado cuenta. Sin más contexto, pues sería otra interpretación válida, como "quiero cogerte de lo micro". Implicas que la otra parte tiene algo "micro" o "nano".

Comment: @GretaTesorro according to the linked question in Colombia "coger" doesn't have that connotation/meaning, but my guess is that whoever wrote might be understanding that sometimes it does and that other would get the joke. Also, I should have included this explicitly in my answer, it should be "quiero cogerte de **la** mano". Additional note, since you are new to the site, please don't forget to mark one of the answers as the accepted answer

Comment: Another typo with my username XD No había visto que me respondías

Comment: I don't know but going along with de la mano, the nano could be dick. I want to hold you by your little dick. [e]nano. where dwarf could possibly mean that.

Answer (score 2):

I also think the sentence makes no sense. Nevertheless, trying to propose something, I think it could actually be a sentence.

**Nano** can be a slang for "enano", which means "very small", "dwarf", "midget"...

This word is very used in the Spanish city of Valencia, where "nano" is a common way to call people... especially if you are a chav (see cani/choni) haha.

But, if we agree that it is originally a shortening from "enano", then your sentence would translate s

> "Quiero cogerte... de lo enano".

Whose translation is not very appropaite to be posted. Personally, I prefer the "mano" version haha.

This is just wondering. I have no idea, actually, the sentence is weird. Also, if you could provide more context, like where you heard it, that would help.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any more context, that was the only thing it said on a (apart from that) blank paper. But you're right, that sentence makes no sense haha!