# Coger: origen de su significado sexual en algunos países

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, sexualidad

*Coger* es un verbo bastante usado en España. Sin embargo, en algunos países de Hispanoamérica, como México, tiene connotaciones sexuales. ¿Esto a raíz de qué surgió? ¿Por qué y cuándo?

Comment: Como referencia, en [¿En qué países la palabra “coger” tiene connotaciones sexuales?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8749/1674) hay un buen listado de dónde tiene tal connotación. Sobre el origen, ¿has podido investigar algo?

Comment: Interesting side note: The generic translation for "coger" into German is "nehmen" which 'default' meaning is quite similar to coger. E.g. to take a bus, to grab an object etc. But "nehmen" can also be used in a sexual way, listed in Duden under pt 19, https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nehmen.

So, this might not be specific to Spanish and I'm wondering how coger relates to nehmen in that sense.

Comment: @Em1 In French, the equivalent would be *prendre* which can also have this meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corominas recoge esto sobre la origen de este uso:

> El sentido sexual *coger* es ya antiguo y fué corriente aun en España... pero en América, donde esta acepción se ha afirmado más, ello ha sido causa, por razones de pudor, de la decadencia de **coger** en llas demás acepciones...
>
> - Joan Corominas, *Diccionario crítico etimológico de la lengua castellana* (1954)

Creo que proviene de su uso como sinónimo de [*tomar*](https://dle.rae.es/?w=tomar),<sup>1</sup> que también significa:

> 23. tr. Dicho del macho: Cubrir a la hembra.

↓

> 13) Cubrir el macho a la hembra. [*DLE*, 18th ed., 1956]

Inicialmente usado como eufemismo referido a humanos en Andalucía:

> En Granada y otras partes, tener acto venéreo. [*Castro y Rossi*, 1852]

Y de ahí su uso americano:

> *Am. m.* vulg. Tener acto carnal con una mujer. [*Salvá*, 1846]

Hay eufemismos análogos en inglés por ejemplo (["to take; to have"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:copulate_with) etc).

---

<sup>**Fuente:** [*A history of six Spanish verbs meaning "to take, seize, grasp"*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iY1dDwAAQBAJ)</sup>
<sup>**1.** "...it has been shown that such usage of *coger = tomar* existed in the Middle Ages."</sup>

Comment: Fascinating that we use cover too but only, I think, for horses: the stallion covers the mare.

Answer (score 0):

A mí un mexicano me contó que viene de cuando los españoles violaban a nativas. Las elegían con la frase, "esa me la cojo yo" (esa la elijo yo) y acabó como verbo. Similar al "show me now/chumino".